# How to associate a valid service email address with a google cloud platform project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api

I have a data processing web service that accepts a google spreadsheet as input. A spreadsheet owner enables my data service to read the spreadsheet by sharing the sheet with the service email. This works well and was surprisingly easy to setup.

But the service email is not a valid email address and generates a DNS error in the users mailbox. The service also does not receive a notification that a spreadsheet has been shared.

Is there a way to associate a valid public email address with my Google project that would allow it to receive the sharing notification sent by sharing the spreadsheet? This would ideally also be the email address that the spreadsheet owner used to share the sheet with the service.

Comment: Haven't tried your use case yet but since you're using a web app, have you tried using [Google Sign-in for Web](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)?

Comment: @noogui Thanks, but it's actually a server-to-server app: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts and the spreadsheet owner can share a sheet with the service via email just like she can share it with any other user, and in control of how much access is granted. The service just doesn't get the 'shared with you...' notification email because the Iam.gserviseaccount.com domain is not an email-enabled domain.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not implemented. Service accounts have email addresses like example@[project-id].iam.gserviceaccount.com but these are currently only identifiers and don't have mailboxes (in fact their domains don't resolve to an IP address and there is no MX record). This might eventually change but currently it is not possible to receive mail for service accounts.

A possible workaround is to use 3-legged OAuth to get access to your users' complete drive data (instead of just that one document). This might not be a viable option since giving an application access to the drive scope is a very serious commitment.

There is one workaround that I want to mention since people might think of it but it's a **bad** idea: you could create a Google consumer (GMail) account and get a 3-legged OAuth token for it using the GMail scope (to receive email) and the Drive scope (to access documents shared with it). I strongly recommend against using something like this in a production environment since consumer accounts are not built for service account scenarios (e.g. mailbox size, email reception QPS before abuse protection is triggered, credential exchanges, ...). A solution like this will eventually blow up.

Comment: Thanks @Shirky re: "...giving an application access to the drive scope is a very serious commitment." ...and was rejected as a solution by our primary stakeholders. It would seem to be a highly useful feature for a service account to have an email (or some other notification) alias on which it could receive, and act on, notifications sent directly from a Drive account. Is there a place to request such a feature from the Google developers?

Comment: We are tracking this feature but it is sadly currently at a lower priority than other efforts to improve service accounts. I do understand that this is a very convenient feature to have!